# Where is R.java generated?

Tags: android

I know there are already tons of questions regarding R not being generated. My problem is that R.java is generated in a different package. So I have two questions.

1) Is the package location where R.java is generated determined by AndroidManifest.xml

2) If I put another Activity in a different package (ex. ToolActivity.java in "com.mydomain.utils"), R shows it cannot be resolved unless I add "import com.mydomain.R". Is this right or this is not best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Is the package location where R.java is generated determined by
>   AndroidManifest.xml

Yes. Inside `<manifest package="you.package.here" />` attribute.

> 2) If I put another Activity in a different package (ex.
>   ToolActivity.java in "com.mydomain.utils"), R shows it cannot be
>   resolved unless I add "import com.mydomain.R". Is this right or this
>   is not best practice?

You have to import generated `R` class into any other package. This is usual and the only practice.

Answer (score 0):

R.Java is automatically created inside build folder. You do not have to do anything. Also don't edit R.java because it is created every time you compile your project. R.java file basically contains all the id's of the views declared in your layout files.